# Export .ply file from .blend file

Tags: uv, export, color, vertex-colors

I'm facing a problem exporting a .ply file with colour information from a .blend file in Blender 3.5. While in the blender my object is displayed with the right texture when I export the file in .ply format, having selected the box "Vertex colors", no RGB information appears in the exported .ply file. Below you can see an image with the structure of the mesh file.What should i do in order to extract color information? Thank you very much! [image]

Comment: From the [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/import_export/mesh_ply.html#stanford-ply) it looks as if the exporter isn't complete. In any case there have always been problems importing and exporting materials between different applications due to the different standards used. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures for a comprehensive writeup.